# Redirect to url last action before Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

I have a route which runs a scritpt and I want to finish running when the redirect url where it came from such action, as this route is associated controller pordra even be accessed for execution from different sites of application

eg

index -> running Routing-> terminates and redirects to index.

post -> running Routing-> terminates and redirects to post.

...

bone according to redirecting from where the action

my question is whether there is some method in laravel 4 to capture the url or path where the application is to run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `Redirect::back()`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you just after the previous URL?

If so, you can use [URL::previous()](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.UrlGenerator.html#66-74).